# Constantly update console using cpp (msfs2020 SimConnect)

Tags: c++

[image: example picture]

Im trying to constantly update the console number related to altitude. At the moment its a static number, and does not update while the plane is gaining, or loosing altitude. There is a comment near the bottom of the text referring to the prinf() that im using to send it to console(not sure what all was needed to be seen so I sent it all).

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include "SimConnect.h"

using namespace std;

HANDLE hSimConnect = NULL;

enum DATA_DEFINE_ID {
  DEFINITION_ID_AP,
};

enum DATA_REQUEST_ID {
  REQUEST_AP_SETTINGS,
};

enum EVENT_ID {
  EVENT_SET_AP_ALTITUDE,
};

struct DataRefs {
  double altitude;
  double knots;
};

int main() {
  HRESULT hr;
  SIMCONNECT_RECV* pData = NULL;
  DWORD cbData = 0;
  bool bRequestProcessed = false;
  int SelectedAltitude = 0;
  SIMCONNECT_RECV_SIMOBJECT_DATA* pObjData = NULL;
  DataRefs* pDataRefs = NULL;

  if (SUCCEEDED(SimConnect_Open(&hSimConnect, "Client Event", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL))) {
    printf("Connected to MSFS2020!\n");
  } else {
    printf("Failed to Connect to MSFS2020\n");
  }

  // simVars
  hr = SimConnect_AddToDataDefinition(hSimConnect, DEFINITION_ID_AP,"PLANE ALTITUDE", "Feet");

  // Check simVars
  hr = SimConnect_RequestDataOnSimObject(
      hSimConnect, REQUEST_AP_SETTINGS, DEFINITION_ID_AP,
      SIMCONNECT_OBJECT_ID_USER, SIMCONNECT_PERIOD_ONCE);

  if (FAILED(hr)) {
    printf("RequestDataOnSimObject for AutopilotData structure - error\n");
  }

  bRequestProcessed = false;

  while (!bRequestProcessed) {
    hr = SimConnect_GetNextDispatch(hSimConnect, &pData, &cbData);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
      pObjData = (SIMCONNECT_RECV_SIMOBJECT_DATA*)pData;
      pDataRefs = (DataRefs*)&pObjData->dwData;
      // This line of code is what im referring to
      printf("\rCurrent  altitude: %.f feet", pDataRefs->altitude);
    }
  }

  // Close
  hr = SimConnect_Close(hSimConnect);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you even know that the sim is returning multiple values?  Maybe it isn't.  Try replacing the `\r` with `\n` and see if multiple lines are printed out.  Or use other debugging techniques, such as attaching a debugger and stepping through your program's execution.  Examine memory contents and try to determine which actual part of your program is responsible.  Also worth noting that if the type of `dwData` member is actually `DWORD` (as the name suggests) then it can only be converted to a pointer IF your program is compiled as 32-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. I was using `SIMCONNECT_PERIOD_ONCE` when I should have been using `SIMCONNECT_PERIOD_SECOND`.

(the various interval enums are documented over on https://docs.flightsimulator.com/html/Programming_Tools/SimConnect/API_Reference/Structures_And_Enumerations/SIMCONNECT_PERIOD.htm)